# How to make optional lookbehind and lookahead in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to extract the text between **de** and **en** as well as the text in the strings that don't have **de** or **en**. I am not very good with regex but after reading about lookaheads and lookbehinds I managed to get partly what I want. Now I have to make them optional but whatever I've tried, I can't get it right.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

```r
library(stringr)
(sstring = c('{\"de\":\"extract this one\",\"en\":\"some text\"}',     'extract this one',     '{\"de\":\"extract this one\",\"en\":\"some text\"}', "p (340) extract this one"))
#> [1] "{\"de\":\"extract this one\",\"en\":\"some text\"}"
#> [2] "extract this one"                                  
#> [3] "{\"de\":\"extract this one\",\"en\":\"some text\"}"
#> [4] "p (340) extract this one"

str_extract_all(string = sstring, pattern = "(?<=.de\":\").*(?=.,\"en\":)")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "extract this one"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "extract this one"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> character(0)
```

desired output:

```r
#> [1] "extract this one"         "extract this one"        
#> [3] "extract this one"         "p (340) extract this one"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Base R

```
gsub('.*de\":\"(.*)\",\"en.*',"\\1",sstring)


[1] "extract this one"        
[2] "extract this one"        
[3] "extract this one"        
[4] "p (340) extract this one"
```

Where:

- `.*` indicates any length of any character
- `(...)` brackets store whats inside to latter be recalled by `"\\1"` 
  Essentially, were subbing the entire string with the matching patterns with only the text we want.

Comment: thank you very very much! for the explanations as well! I have really messy data and this approach captures really everything b/n de and en. I couldn't recreate properly the messiness of the data I work with but your code accounts for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a pattern that will match any string not containing `{"de":"` substring or a substring after `{"de":"` that contains 1+ chars other than `"`:

```
(?<=\{"de":")[^"]+|^(?!.*\{"de":").+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cizF6o/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=\{"de":")` - a positive lookbehind that looks for a position immediately 
  preceded with `{"de":"`
- `[^"]+` - then extracts 1+ chars other than `"`
- `|` - or
- `^` - at the start of string
- `(?!.*\{"de":")` - make sure there is no `{"de":"` in the string and
- `.+` - extract 1+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

See an [R demo online](https://rextester.com/BHYMBE29715):

```
library(stringr)
sstring = c('{\"de\":\"extract this one\",\"en\":\"some text\"}',     'extract this one',     '{\"de\":\"extract this one\",\"en\":\"some text\"}', "p (340) extract this one")
str_extract( sstring, '(?<=\\{"de":")[^"]+|^(?!.*\\{"de":").+')
# => [1] "extract this one"         "extract this one"        
#    [3] "extract this one"         "p (340) extract this one"
```